# How to change date format in with query along with sorting

Tags: postgresql, date, to-char

Here it is my query, I want to convert date format to 'HH:MI am, DD Month YYYY' and it should be ascending order

```
with  a1 as (
    select
        replace(ccfd.comments, ',', '!@#$%'),
        uu.fname,
        ccfd.create_date
    from 
        revenue_accounting.cpu_comment_form_details as ccfd
    left join 
        users.users as uu on uu.id = ccfd.updated_by
    where 
        ccfd.cpu_form_id = 1762
    order by 
        ccfd.create_date
)
select 
    array_to_string(array_agg(array[fname,replace,create_date::text]::text),',') from a1
```

Comment: `to_char(create_date, '....')`?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `array_to_string(array_agg(..), ',')` can be replaced with `string_agg(..., ',')`

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name. working fine